# Android Activities do not get garbage collected

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Let's say i have 2 Activities, A and B.

From Activity A, i'll start Activity B with StartActivity(Intent). I close Activity B via finish().

Now, Android will run out of memory. Maybe not for some time, because B is empty, or whatever, but the garbage collector just wont clean activity B... even on low memory.

Where could this behaviour come from? I have no listeners, events, or contexts used anywhere in activity B, and still, GC will NOT mark it as unused/clearable...

"Post your code" is not an option here, im just using StartActivity and Finish in empty activities.

Comment: you finished your activity A ??

Comment: No, because i want to go back to Activity A. I Finish activity B to go back to activity A, if i repeat this process, my memory will fill up with instances of activity B

Comment: What makes you think that GC will not clean activity B?

Comment: because i get an out of memory exception :p

Comment: Story is, i have an app, with some large activities, after a while, it runs out of memory, so i started to investigate. opened a new solution, with to empty activities, even in this project, the memory will slowly decrease when opening and closing activity B

Comment: i think by mistake you set the property  android:noHistory = "true" in your activity A .